# Why is the default value of fill-column 70?

Tags: fill-column

Is there a reason that the default value of `fill-column` is `70`?

In my experience, everyone who cares about the value of `fill-column` prefers a default value of `80`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may have been intended for plain text emails, which get quoted in replies by adding a character (usually `>`) and often a space at the beginning of each line. 70 columns allow 8 levels of quoting on an 80-column terminal (8 `>` plus a space plus the rightmost column is reserved for a continuation character to indicate that the line overflows). Back in the days of physical terminals, 80 columns was a de facto standard.

```
Dominique wrote:
> Charlie wrote:
>> Bob wrote:
>>> Alice wrote:
>>>> I'm first!
>>> Second.
>> Third.
> Fourth.

Fifth.

-- 
Eve
```

I don't know for sure, however. I don't have a reference. It may well be that the column width dates back from before this email convention. But 80 columns was a very common terminal width even before Emacs existed, so 70 can't come from that alone.

The [GNU coding standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Formatting) requests a width of 79 characters (that's relevant to `fill-column` for string literals and comments), but that was [added](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/gnustandards/gnustandards/standards.texi?view=log#rev1.233) much later than the choice of the default value of `fill-column` in Emacs.

Comment: Hollerith (aka punch) cards had/have 80 columns. For some languages (e.g. Fortran) the last several columns were reserved for comments. 80 columns is older than terminal widths - it is older than terminals...